# Word2Vec Skip Gram Concept/Training Clarifications

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I’m implementing the Skip Gram Model from scratch for a project of mine but have a few questions I need cleared up to get the full understanding:

1) What is the size of the output layer? I’m getting mixed information on it. Some says it’s the size of the entire vocabulary list, others say it’s only as big as your window size so that it spans the context words you have for that particular input.

2) How often do I update my parameters? Is it once per set of data points? Once per full sentence? Once for the entire dataset and then rerun the model?

3) How does the soft max classifier turn the output of the model into a one hot vector since the soft max returns [0, 1] while the one hot is only 0 OR 1? Do I take the highest number and set that as my [0, 0, ... 1 ... 0]?

4) In regards to training the model, after getting this one hot vector in part 3, how do I interpret the loss? Is it if my output doesn’t match my input, then it means it was wrong?